# DateTime.Now and NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, datetime

In my business object I have to obtain the current hour (a DateTime with minutes and seconds = 0).

I have created a function like this:

```
private DateTime GetCurrentHour() 
{ 
        return DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour); 
}
```

If I use it in this way

```
var lastHour=GetCurrentHour();
```

I get a NullReferenceException 
????

Using in the same function in this way:

```
var ora = new NHRepository<OraProduzione>(Session) 
               .First(x => x.Data == GetCurrentHour().AddHours(-1));
```

I get no exception
Why?

This is the stacktrace:

```
   in ImpelSystems.Produzione.Business.Calendario.TimerWakeUp() in \Calendario.cs:riga 115
   in ImpelSystems.Produzione.Business.Calendario.<.ctor>b__1(Object x) in \Calendario.cs:riga 78
   in System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(Object state)
```

TimerWakeUp is executed on a Timer created with

```
timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x => TimerWakeUp(), null, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10));
```

Comment: You can get the current hour like this DateTime.Now.Hour Why are you using this Today.AddHour(DateTime.Now.Hour)?

Comment: Are you sure the exception happens on that line ? There is nothing in that method that can throw a NullReferenceException...

Comment: Exception is on var lastHour=GetCurrentHour();  Visual Studio stops there...

Comment: Could you post the stack trace ?

Comment: @Mauro: The code runs fine in my test. That line truly **cannot** produce that exception; it's somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the code for `TimerWakeUp`?

Comment: I have added in the beginning of TimerWakeUp this:

DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime t2 = DateTime.Today;
                DateTime t3 = DateTime.UtcNow;
                DateTime lastHour = DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour);

all works... but no the last one!

Comment: Can you step into the operation in the debugger?

Comment: It seems to be a problem of PropertyChanged events... don't ask me more.. i'll try to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that your exception is on `var lastHour=GetCurrentHour();`? The `DateTime` type is a struct, which should make it (unless I'm missing something) impossible for you to encounter a null reference.

Additionally, I'm assuming you meant `DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour)`, as the `Today` property is static, so you couldn't access it from the instance returned from `Now`.

Comment: +1. Note that neither GetCurrentHour() nor DateTime show up in the stack trace.